# Mongo - Count of empty double nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongotemplate

Say I have this structure

```
{
    "_id" : "4klhrj5hZ",
    "name" : "asdf",
    "startTime" : ISODate("2016-09-20T22:22:08.082Z"),
    "columns" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e1b69087ceb4392ebdf7f4"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-20T22:22:08.088Z"),
            "rows" : [
                {
                    "value" : "adf",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("57e1b7867598bd39a72876ef")
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e1b69087ceb4392ebdf7f3"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-20T22:22:08.088Z"),
            "rows" : [
                {
                    "value" : "we",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("57e1b69287ceb4392ebdf7f5"),
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e1b69087ceb4392ebdf7f2"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-20T22:22:08.086Z"),
            "rows" : [
                {
                    "value" : "asdf",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("57e1b7be7598bd39a72876f0")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where I first have an array of columns, then an array of rows with each columns. An array of arrays...  I'm trying to write a count query to tell me how many top level documents contain **ALL** empty array of arrays.  So in this example, `columns[0-2].rows.length === 0`, not columns could be any length.  The thing that is tripping me up the most from examples i've seen, is the doing the nested array dynamically and not referring to it like

`columns.0.rows`

Thanks!

**EDIT: Clarification**
Here is the mongoose schema to help clarify

```
var RowSchema = new Schema({
  value: String,
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
});

var ColumnSchema = new Schema({
  rows: [RowSchema],
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
});

var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    'default': shortid.generate
  },
  name: String,
  columns: [ColumnSchema],
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    'default': Date.now
  }
})
```

I want to run a query to find all `Item`'s that contain zero rows in **all** columns. So I know how to find an array that is empty:

```
Item.find({ columns: { $exists: true, $eq: [] } })
```

But I want something like

```
Item.find({ 'columns.rows': { $exists: true, $eq: [] } })
```

Sorry for the unclear explanation, just get so wrapped up in it sometimes you forget to set the proper context. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear  what exactly your expected query is. What does empty arrays of arrays mean? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added clarification. Thanks!